# How to do inplace replacement in a file using perl

Tags: regex, perl, shell

Here is my input file

```
{1:ABCDEFGHXXX}{2:I300IRVTUKAXXXX}
:20:REFERENCE
:82A:IRVTUKYXXX
:87A:ABCDEF
```

I need to change the line `82A:IRVTUKYXXX` to `82A:IRVTUK0XXX`
That means I have to find the 8th character after :82: and replace that with 0

Do we have any perl script or command to replace any character at the particular position. In this case it is 8th character from the pattern i am going to match.

Comment: You example indicates that you replace the 7th character after :82A:

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<=:82A.{7})./0/' file

cat file
{1:ABCDEFGHXXX}{2:I300IRVTUKAXXXX}
:20:REFERENCE
:82A:IRVTUK0XXX
:87A:ABCDEF
```

Comment: Can you pls explain how does it works? How does < works? As a input redirection or less than operator?

Comment: @user2892124: `(?<=...)` is syntax for lookbehind which means find a character that is preceded by `:82A` and 7 characters.

Comment: Thnq.. Its is uselful. Can you also tell how to do same replacement with certain range. For example in this same example how to replace 6th to 10th character.. I am. New to perl and tried changing the above command doesnt work..

Comment: Sure you can do: `perl -i -pe 's/(?<=:82A.{5}).{5}/0/' file`

Comment: Also if original answer worked you can you mark the answer as accepted. You can still comment here clearing your doubts.